# At what point will I have any revenue money using iAd banners?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, iad

I have an app which has been on the App Store for around two weeks and has 170 downloads so far. I am using iAd banners and I have some friends who have clicked on the banner and it says I have made $0 so far, at what point is this likely to change ? Is it possible that apple has an error or I have made an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of that depends if you have set up iAd correctly and linked everything to your account and are enrolled in the iAd contract. If you did link everything and are have agreed to the contract with Apple about iAd, then you may not get revenue very quickly from them. iAd works on a CPM basis, which is Cost Per Mille 
which means that the advertiser pays per 1000 impressions or clicks. You have to have way more then just a "few clicks from your friends" to start earning actual revenue. Also, your friends pressing the banners is against the iAd rules and terms and could get you banned, so I would highly advise against it. Lastly, you should just check if the following apple:

1) Linked up code to custom Identifier from Apple 
2) Signed the iAd worldwide contract with Apple
3) Set up everything correctly

If all those were made you have to wait and earn more to start earning.

Hope that helps,
Julian

Comment: Thanks for the answer I just realized I needed to go to the iAd network to really see the revenue and I do have a few cents :) on a side note I didn't tell anyone to click on the ad banners, they just told me they had done it so it's all good ! thanks again for your answer !